# Массовая перекодировка файлов

Tags: файлы, кодировка

Здравствуйте, у меня проблемы с кодировкой в файлах, файлов большое кол-во в папках, думал поискать программу которая конвертирует кодировку файла в UTF-8 (без BOM), но так и не смог найти, может кто посоветует что нибуть?

Comment: файлы на калькуляторе?

Comment: Файлы сайта: php, js, tpl

Comment: тут что-то очень похожее обсуждалось
http://hashcode.ru/questions/92598/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Мне бы программку

Answer (score 4):

Гугл говорит, что есть такой способ:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
  directory="$1"        # Если каталог задан в командной строке при вызове сценария
else
  directory="$PWD"      # Иначе просматривается текущий каталог.
fi

if [ -n "$2" ]
then
file_ext="$2"           # Расширение файлов, которые нужно переконвертировать, если задано в командной строке при вызове сценария 
else
file_ext=php          # Иначе будут переконвертированы все .php файлы.
fi

if [ -n "$3" ]
then
addition="$3"            #добавка к имени конвертированного файла, если задано в командной строке при вызове сценария
else
addition=_converted    # Иначе к имени файла будет добавлено _converted.
fi

for i in "$directory"/*.$file_ext;
 do
   fname=`basename "$i" .$file_ext`
   cat "$i" | recode -f WINDOWS-1251..UTF-8 > "$directory"/"$fname"$addition.$file_ext;
 done
```

Алсо еще как вариант - рекурсивно обходить с помощью похапе файлы (glob, смекаете?), прогонять через упомянутый iconv, и пересохранять. Чо получится - не знаю. Возможно и файл весом в нуль байт.

Comment: Я ищу готовое решение, готовую программу с exe расширением, спасибо за ваш пример, но я не знаю что с ним делать : ) мне нужно то всего лишь перекодировать все фалы своего сайта

Comment: @dogmar, тогда вы не по адресу.

Answer (score 3):

iconv
это поточная утилита перекодировки, man iconv

```
find . -type f -exec iconv '{}' -f koi8-r -t utf-8 -o tmp ';' -a -exec mv tmp '{}' ';'
```

Поменяйте koi8-r на windows-1251 или что там у вас

Поставьте MSYS или cygwin если у вас windows.

Comment: Это перекодировка строки, мне нужно перекодировать файлы причем массово и рекурсивно по всем папкам.

Comment: @dogmar, исправил ответ, смотрите

Comment: @sercxjo: наверное, стоит добавить опцию `-type f` к вызову `find`.

Comment: @VladD да, добавил, но и без неё iconv на директории просто спотыкается и mv пропускается